# IBM Rational Clear Case 9.0.1 Installation

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

Currently we are trying to setup a server IBM Rational Clear Case 9.0.1 and can anyone help with pre-requisites for this setup and what all we need to install to make this code repository working.

Answer (score 0):

The main documentation remains the [IBM Support - Rational ClearCase 9.0.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24043585), which does include prerequisites like:

- Installing [IBM Installation Manager 1.8.2](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24039012) or later
- [Installing ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.help.ic.doc/topics/c_node_installing.htm),
- Or: [Upgrading ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.help.ic.doc/topics/c_node_upgrading.htm).

Comment: Thanks VonC. Can you clarify on below version which will be compatible for below Rational License Key Server version:
Clear Case remote client version: 9.0.1
Plugin version: ??
Rich Client Platform Version: ?? Also If you have installation guidelines document based on your real time experience, can you please share me

Comment: @Vijay I only know of compatibility matrix for CC 7 and 8, not 9: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674